# Geb Browser automation with filemaker

Tags: java, grails, groovy, geb

I have doubt with GEB browser automation. The URL will be opened via filemaker web viewer and then we to geb automation process. Is it possible? Can You provide any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geb uses Selenium which uses drivers to open a browser. When it is opened it has a handle on the process to drive this browser. If something else has opened the browser Geb cannot suddenly hijack this control.

In short must have a handle on the browser process to be able to drive it.

You can select CONTROLLED browser windows using

withWindow(window title) {
}

[Geb Manual - withWindow](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/browser.html#switching_context_to_already_opened_windows)